# Fill all gaps between starting and ending dates with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
user_df = read.table(text = "person_id job_number job_type start_date end_date
                  1 1 B 2012-11-01 2014-01-01
                  1 2 A 2016-02-01 2016-10-01
                  1 3 A 2016-12-01 2020-01-01
                  1 4 B 2020-01-01 2021-01-01
                  2 1 A 2011-03-01 2012-08-01
                  2 2 B 2013-01-01 2020-01-01
                  2 3 A 2020-01-01 2021-01-01
                  2 4 B 2021-01-01 2021-01-17
                  3 1 A 2005-03-01 2011-03-01
                  3 2 B 2012-01-01 2014-01-01", header = T)
```

Each `person_id` has a start and an ending date for a given job. I would like to insert rows in between the empty space between jobs, and create an additional column called `unemployed` that is set to 1 for those columns.

The resulting data.frame for the first several rows would look like this:

```
user_df = read.table(text = "person_id job_number job_type start_date end_date unemployed
                  1 1 B 2012-11-01 2014-01-01 0
                  1 1 B 2014-01-01 2016-02-01 1
                  1 2 A 2016-02-01 2016-10-01 0
                  1 2 A 2016-10-01 2016-12-01 1
                  1 3 A 2016-12-01 2020-01-01 0
                  1 4 B 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 0
                  2 1 A 2011-03-01 2012-08-01 0
                  2 1 A 2012-08-01 2013-01-01 1
                  2 2 B 2013-01-01 2020-01-01 0", header = T)
```

So I'm essentially inserting a new row with the previous rows' end date as its start date and the next row's start date as its end date.

Not sure where to even start with this. I was able to compute the total amount of time spent unemployed by simply summing up the days spanning the earliest start date and the last ending date and subtracting that from the total time actually accumulated by each row. But I'm not sure how I'd go about programatically inserting rows within a dplyr chain to fill in the unemployed time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
user_df %>%
  arrange(start_date) %>%
  group_by(person_id) %>%
  mutate(nextstart = lead(start_date)) %>%
  filter(end_date < nextstart) %>%
  mutate(start_date = end_date, end_date = nextstart, unemployed = 1L) %>%
  select(-nextstart) %>%
  bind_rows(mutate(user_df, unemployed = 0L)) %>%
  arrange(person_id, start_date) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 14 x 6
#    person_id job_number job_type start_date end_date   unemployed
#        <int>      <int> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>           <int>
#  1         1          1 B        2012-11-01 2014-01-01          0
#  2         1          1 B        2014-01-01 2016-02-01          1
#  3         1          2 A        2016-02-01 2016-10-01          0
#  4         1          2 A        2016-10-01 2016-12-01          1
#  5         1          3 A        2016-12-01 2020-01-01          0
#  6         1          4 B        2020-01-01 2021-01-01          0
#  7         2          1 A        2011-03-01 2012-08-01          0
#  8         2          1 A        2012-08-01 2013-01-01          1
#  9         2          2 B        2013-01-01 2020-01-01          0
# 10         2          3 A        2020-01-01 2021-01-01          0
# 11         2          4 B        2021-01-01 2021-01-17          0
# 12         3          1 A        2005-03-01 2011-03-01          0
# 13         3          1 A        2011-03-01 2012-01-01          1
# 14         3          2 B        2012-01-01 2014-01-01          0
```

Technically, this is comparing by the alphabetic sort of dates; in this case, its effect is the same (the format is good for that) though it'll be slightly less efficient (integer/numeric sorting is faster than alphabetic sorting).

This works by first creating and then capture just the unemployed periods of time,

```r
user_df %>%
  arrange(start_date) %>%
  group_by(person_id) %>%
  mutate(nextstart = lead(start_date)) %>%
  filter(end_date < nextstart)
# # A tibble: 4 x 6
# # Groups:   person_id [3]
#   person_id job_number job_type start_date end_date   nextstart 
#       <int>      <int> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
# 1         3          1 A        2005-03-01 2011-03-01 2012-01-01
# 2         2          1 A        2011-03-01 2012-08-01 2013-01-01
# 3         1          1 B        2012-11-01 2014-01-01 2016-02-01
# 4         1          2 A        2016-02-01 2016-10-01 2016-12-01
```

then shifting the variables, then adding `unemployed`, and then finally returning it to the original dataset. In this case, I added `unemployed` to the original mid-`bind_rows`; where to do this is mostly preference.

Comment: Wow, this is fantastically clever! thanks so much. Learned a lot from reading this code.

Comment: hopefully quick follow-up question. I noticed in my data some participants have dates in one row that are between the starting and end dates of another row. If, for example, they are doing two jobs concurrently, one between 2005-03-01 - 2011-03-01 and the other between 2006-03-01 and 2007-03-01. Do you have any guesses as to how to deal with these cases?

Comment: That's a trick question: to me, that's perfectly valid data. It sounds like it's not aligned with your downstream processing, though. For instance, is it that you assume no two rows (for one person) can overlap *at all*? If that's the case, how to you want to handle conflicts? Shortest job? Longest job? Union of the two jobs (min start and max end)? That's completely contextual, and something you have to define completely. And no, there's no tool that's going to do all of that for you, since it's your constraints. (But yes, it can be done, with well-defined rules.)

Comment: Hmm, sorry -- I should have been more specific. I'm going to create a new question and I will link it here if you're interested in answering.