# Identify date ranges within user that are contained by other date ranges in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Let's say I have the following data:

```
user_df = read.table(text = "start_date_proper end_date_proper id
1995-01-01 1997-12-31 1
1999-04-01 2000-06-30 1
2006-05-01 2009-08-31 1
2010-01-01 2011-12-31 1
2011-01-01 2011-12-31 1
2000-07-01 2020-12-31 1
2003-01-01 2020-12-31 1", header = T)
```

Thanks to this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66321691/fill-all-gaps-between-starting-and-ending-dates-with-dplyr/66321813?noredirect=1#comment117532422_66321813), I was able to identify whenever there were gaps between the end date of one row and the start date of the next and insert a new row that fills that gap. Like so:

```
user_df = user_df %>%
    arrange(start_date_proper) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(nextstart = lead(start_date_proper)) %>%
    filter(end_date_proper < nextstart) %>%
    mutate(start_date_proper = end_date_proper, end_date_proper = nextstart, unemployed = 1L) %>%
    select(-nextstart) %>%
    bind_rows(mutate(user_df, unemployed = 0L)) %>%
    arrange(id, start_date_proper) %>%
    ungroup()

> user_df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   start_date_proper end_date_proper    id unemployed
   <chr>             <chr>           <int>      <int>
 1 1995-01-01        1997-12-31          1          0
 2 1997-12-31        1999-04-01          1          1
 3 1999-04-01        2000-06-30          1          0
 4 2000-06-30        2000-07-01          1          1
 5 2000-07-01        2020-12-31          1          0
 6 2003-01-01        2020-12-31          1          0
 7 2006-05-01        2009-08-31          1          0
 8 2009-08-31        2010-01-01          1          1
 9 2010-01-01        2011-12-31          1          0
10 2011-01-01        2011-12-31          1          0
```

However, notice that the new row identified as unemployed `2009-08-31       -2010-01-01`), is actually not accurate since the user was working from `2003-01-01 - 2020-12-31` in one of the other rows.

So the question is, is there a simple way to identify these cases and set `unemployed` appropriately? My first thought is to iterate over each of the dates where `unemployed == 1` and then iterate over all the other dates within a user and see if those dates contain the dates spanned by the `unemployed ==1 row. But this would require quite a few comparisons, which will be challenging with my big dataset. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand how being unemployed in 2000 is affected by employment in 2003-2020.

Comment: @r2evans, had a brain fart and accidentally copied a dataset with the rows already filled in. Let me correct this.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you are working with `character` dates instead of `Date`-class dates?

Comment: No reason, except that your earlier solution arranged things alphabetically and it seemed to work pretty effectively. Elsewhere in the code I use Date classes. And terribly sorry about the earlier mistake, I since corrected the example.

Comment: Yeah, I tried not to soap-box in that answer, too. I suggest you use `Date`-class unless you have strong reason not to. I don't think it affects things here, since R's `min`/`pmin` and such still do the comparisons the same ... *in this case* ... but I don't like relying on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to work on the premise that there are unemployed periods within periods of employment within the data. To do that, I'm going to change the sample data so that the unemployed periods falls in one of the other periods. (It's not critical, but it's helpful for demonstration and my understanding.)

```r
user_df$start_date_proper[4] <- "2004-06-30"
user_df$end_date_proper[4] <- "2004-07-01"
```

For this trick to work, we need *order*. That is, we need to assume that one row's `start_date_proper` (if unemployed) must be no earlier than the preceding row's `end_date_proper`; similarly, an unemployed `end_date_proper` must be no later than the next row's `start_date_proper`. For this, I'll use the vectorized min/max functions: `pmin` and `pmax`:

Now the work:

```r
user_df %>%
  arrange(start_date_proper) %>%
  mutate(
    start_date_proper = if_else(
      unemployed > 0,
      pmax(start_date_proper, lag(end_date_proper), na.rm = TRUE),
      start_date_proper),
    end_date_proper = if_else(
      unemployed > 0,
      pmin(end_date_proper, lead(start_date_proper), na.rm = TRUE),
      end_date_proper)
  )
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    start_date_proper end_date_proper    id unemployed
#    <chr>             <chr>           <int>      <int>
#  1 1995-01-01        1997-12-31          1          0
#  2 1997-12-31        1999-04-01          1          0
#  3 1999-04-01        2000-06-30          1          0
#  4 2000-07-01        2020-12-31          1          0
#  5 2003-01-01        2020-12-31          1          0
#  6 2020-12-31        2004-07-01          1          1
#  7 2006-05-01        2009-08-31          1          0
#  8 2009-08-31        2010-01-01          1          0
#  9 2010-01-01        2011-12-31          1          0
# 10 2011-01-01        2011-12-31          1          0
```

Notice now that the unemployed dates have been changed to (1) just after the preceding end, and (2) just before the next row's start. This is obviously an impossible line, so an added filter should be added:

```r
  filter(end_date_proper >= start_date_proper)
```

So the full code (that actually removes that unemployed period) is:

```r
user_df %>%
  arrange(start_date_proper) %>%
  mutate(
    start_date_proper = if_else(
      unemployed > 0,
      pmax(start_date_proper, lag(end_date_proper), na.rm = TRUE),
      start_date_proper),
    end_date_proper = if_else(
      unemployed > 0,
      pmin(end_date_proper, lead(start_date_proper), na.rm = TRUE),
      end_date_proper)
  ) %>%
  filter(end_date_proper >= start_date_proper)
```

In the occasion of incomplete overlap (where only a *portion* of an unemployed period is incorrect), this will constrict the unemployed period so that it no longer overlaps with the preceding and following rows. (This is the rationale for a more complicated approach like this; @JonSpring's answer is far simpler and more readable, but does not deal with overlaps the same.)

that an unemployed region starts in the middle of another period but continues after it, the unemployed region remains, thought with an adjusted start. (This is really the sole reason to go with something more complicated like this answer. @JonSpring's answer is far simpler, but does not allow for this reassignment of dates.)

Comment: Just examined a few test cases on my data, and this seems to be working well. Thank you so much. I was working on this for a full day, and learned a ton from reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the filter line with

```
 filter(end_date_proper < nextstart - 1) %>%
```

since you want to add gap segments only if the start of the next segment is more than a day ahead of the end of the current one.

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  start_date_proper end_date_proper    id unemployed
  <date>            <date>          <int>      <int>
1 1995-01-01        1997-12-31          1          0
2 1997-12-31        1999-04-01          1          0
3 1999-04-01        2000-06-30          1          0
4 2000-07-01        2020-12-31          1          0
5 2003-01-01        2020-12-31          1          0
6 2006-05-01        2009-08-31          1          0
7 2009-08-31        2010-01-01          1          0
8 2010-01-01        2011-12-31          1          0
9 2011-01-01        2011-12-31          1          0
```